# Redirecting Output of print to multiples files in awk

Tags: text-processing, files, awk

I want to print same lines to 2 different files. What I am doing right now is:

```
print ID[i]" "Value[i]" "TS1[i]" "TS2[i] > "file1.txt";
print ID[i]" "Value[i]" "TS1[i]" "TS2[i] > "file2.txt";
```

Can I write a single command to redirect it to two different files ?

**EDIT**

I don't want to print my whole command output to the multiple files, I want to write some of records based on some condition into multiple files,I am printing this within `awk` script so I need an **efficient** way to do it.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You say that they are *same lines*, but then you say that they are not *whole lines*.

Comment: Is it that you want to use a variable? `MYLINE=ID[i]" "...; print MYLINE >> file1.txt; print MYLINE >> file2.txt` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can not do it with `awk`.

Using `tee`, you can do something like this:

```
$ awk '{print ID[i]" "Value[i]" "TS1[i]" "TS2[i]}' file | tee out1 out2
```

Using `tee -a` if you want to append instead of override existed files.

If you don't want to print the whole output, you can try:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {outfile["a.txt"];outfile["b.txt"]}
    { for (file in outfile) { print > file } }' file
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I dont wanna print my whole command output to multiple files.

Comment: You can do the pipe inside awk. `command = "tee file1.txt file2.txt"; print message | command;`

Comment: @mtm: Yes, I want to add it but Stéphane Chazelas had answerd.

Answer (score 11):

Within `awk`, instead of redirecting to a file with `print "text" > "file"`, you can redirect to a command using:

```
print "something" | "tee file1.txt file2.txt"
```

The first time you use that `|`, `awk` spawns the command, and the next time it reuses the same command, so it doesn't start a new `tee` each time you do that and doesn't overwrite the files (you need to call `close("tee file1.txt file2.txt")` if you do want `awk` to start a new command the next time). However, if you do both `> "file1.txt"` and `| "tee file1.txt..."` there will be a conflict.

You may then want to use `>> "file1.txt"` and `| "tee -a file1.txt..."` instead.

However, I'd still go with [@cuonglm's `for` approach](/a/138906) or use an `awk` function as that would be cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: Why did you quote the tee command? Is there any reason behind that?

Comment: @polym: He used pipe inside `awk` script, not in shell like my answer. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html

Comment: @Stephane +1 for nice explanation,thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A [user defined function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/User_002ddefined.html) might make your code cleaner and cause less duplication, if that's what the concern is.

```
function print_to_files( message, file_a, file_b ) {
   print message > file_a;
   print message > file_b;
}

message = sprintf( "%s %s %s %s", ID[i], Value[i], TS1[i], TS2[i] )
print_to_files( message , "filea", "fileb" );'
```

Or hard code the files if that's all you need.

```
function print_to_files( message ) {
   print message > "/path/to/filea";
   print message > "/path/to/fileb";
}

message = sprintf( "%s %s %s %s", ID[i], Value[i], TS1[i], TS2[i] )
print_to_files( message );'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `sed` - but without a clearer idea of your input, I don't know how to demonstrate it specifically. Still, here is a generic example:

```
seq 10 | sed -ne '/1/w ./onesfile.txt' -e '/3/w threesfile.txt'
```

That writes only the lines containing a `1` to the `onesfile.txt` and otherwise for `3` - everything else is deleted. This is a *very* basic example of how this might work, but if you could provide sample input I might do a little better.

Once `sed` opens a file for writing it remains open until the process is completed - it does not continuously truncate its own writes - the file descriptors are retained for the life of the process.